# Python PDFKit Celery RabbitMQ async issue; PDF hangs when trying to parse more than 99 rows in table

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, pdfkit, eventlet

I have a weird problem when trying to generate a pdf using PDFkit2 on Python 3.8 using Celery + RabbitMQ and Eventlet all running on Windows Server 2019. If I call an async function, e.g. gen_pdf.delay('source', 'target'), and the source html table contains more than 99 rows, the wkhtmltopdf portion of PDFKit2 just hangs there forever, no error, no clue. If i call the function directly, e.g. gen_pdf('source', 'target'), from the calling app, it can do unlimited rows using the same html source file. I've tried everything to resolve this, the reason i need it to run asynchronously is that there are hundreds of reports that need to be iterated through and the main thread gets bogged down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've scoured the net to no avail. I've included a sample async task for review.

```
import pdfkit
from celery import Celery

async_task = Celery('async_task')
async_task.config_from_object('async.celeryconfig')

@async_task.task(name='gen_pdf')
def gen_pdf(source, target):
folder = 'some path'    
options = {
            'allow': 'F:\\inetpub\\root\\static\\',
            'header-html': 'F:\\inetpub\\root\\static\\html\\pdf_header.html',
            'footer-html': 'F:\\inetpub\\root\\static\\html\\pdf_footer.html',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
            'page-size': 'Letter',
            'orientation': 'Landscape',
            'margin-top': '0.75in',
            'margin-right': '0.5in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.5in',
            'margin-left': '0.5in',
            'footer-right': '[page] of [topage]',
    }
    # converting html to PDF
    pdfkit.from_file(f'{folder}{source}', f'{folder}{target}', options=options)
```

the celeryconfig

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672//'
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 0
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True}
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY = True
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 100
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///async_tasks.db'
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

and the startup_script

```
celery worker --purge -A async_task -P eventlet -l INFO -n "PDF" -E --autoscale=25,5
```